# android: ads cannot be incorporated to the program

Tags: android, admob, tablelayout, banner

i have just finished my first app and would like to incorporate ad to the bottom of the app. the coding for the ad banner is solely obtained from the Google website at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals, and added to the mainactivity jar. Everything seems fine but then when i run the program, it crashes, logcat and jar coded as follows:

1) How can these be solved? (The program without ads can be run without any error)

2) How to set for ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" ???

3) My xml is a TableLayout, does it matters? (from the logcat it seems cannot properly inflate the ad?)

Many thanks in advance!!

## Jar part:

```
import com.google.ads.*;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest; 
import com.google.ads.AdSize; 
import com.google.ads.AdView; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
    AdView adView;     
    public static final  String MY_PUBLISHER_ID = "a123123123123123c"; //this one is correct 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

      //request TEST ads to avoid being disabled for clicking your own ads         
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();           
      //test mode on EMULATOR         
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);                  
      //test mode on DEVICE (this example code must be replaced with your device unique ID)         
        adRequest.addTestDevice("4G74FC73D62D42B62A7F7DA61EF5F776"); //how to set this? this one is copied from the tutorial only          
      //create a Banner Ad         
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_PUBLISHER_ID);           
      //call the main layout from xml         
        TableLayout mainLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);           
      //add the Banner Ad to our main layout         
        mainLayout.addView(adView);           
      // Initiate a request to load an ad in TEST mode. 
      //  The test mode will work only on emulators and your specific test device, 
      // the users will get real ads.         
        adView.loadAd(adRequest); 
    } 

// ad   
    @Override  
    public void onDestroy() 
    {    
        if (adView != null) {      adView.destroy();    }    
        super.onDestroy();  
    }   
// ad
```

## Logcat as follows:

```
10-10 01:17:34.230: D/dalvikvm(13612): Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-10 01:17:34.650: E/dalvikvm(13612): Could not find class 'com.google.ads.AdRequest', referenced from method com.pearappx.acctcalc.MainActivity.onCreate
10-10 01:17:34.650: W/dalvikvm(13612): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 425 (Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest;) in Lcom/pearappx/acctcalc/MainActivity;
10-10 01:17:34.650: D/dalvikvm(13612): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0009
10-10 01:17:34.650: I/dalvikvm(13612): Could not find method com.google.ads.AdView.destroy, referenced from method com.pearappx.acctcalc.MainActivity.onDestroy
10-10 01:17:34.650: W/dalvikvm(13612): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3042: Lcom/google/ads/AdView;.destroy ()V
10-10 01:17:34.650: D/dalvikvm(13612): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
10-10 01:17:34.650: D/dalvikvm(13612): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0bdf at 0x0b in Lcom/pearappx/acctcalc/MainActivity;.onCreate
10-10 01:17:34.650: I/dalvikvm(13612): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x02e7 at 0x0e in Lcom/pearappx/acctcalc/MainActivity;.onCreate
10-10 01:17:34.700: I/dalvikvm(13612): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x02e8 at 0x1a in Lcom/pearappx/acctcalc/MainActivity;.onCreate
10-10 01:17:34.700: D/dalvikvm(13612): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0be1 at 0x1e in Lcom/pearappx/acctcalc/MainActivity;.onCreate
10-10 01:17:35.085: D/AndroidRuntime(13612): Shutting down VM
10-10 01:17:35.085: W/dalvikvm(13612): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c781f8)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.ads.AdRequest
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at com.pearappx.acctcalc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:94)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
10-10 01:17:35.105: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do these errors occur at compile-time, or runtime only?

Comment: You have 2 ads, one from xml, one in activity via add method, are you sure you need both?

Comment: Re tabbykitten: thanks for pointing out, i have then removed the one in xml. I then run the program and it crashes, logcat posted above, it seems it cannot inflate the ad properly?

Comment: Re Eric: I have removed the ad code in the xml part and remains only the one in JAR part. It then have runtime error as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add admob jar to classpath

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I have now added the admob jar to the classpath and the compiling errors are gone! Thanks!

Comment: yes though the compiling error are gone, it cannot be properly executed. the logcat is posted as above. do you know any idea on how to fix it? many thanks!

Comment: how do you build application? if eclipse you need to go to right click on project > properties > build path > order & export > check admob lib to be exported on device

Comment: it works now after incorporating the add jar to the lib. thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hey follow this [tutorial](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-how-to-add-admob-to-android-in.html)

you have missed to add jar into your libs folder

Comment: thanks! i have read through the tutorial. can i ask how to find such Device ID? Though the tutorial it says find it from the Log info (is it then referring to the LOGCAT?) I cannot find any in the Logcat...